# fold int option function

Tags: polymorphism, sml, fold

I wrote a program that takes integers of lists in lists and adds them together. Now I am trying to write this function again, but using int option integers instead.

I changed my original functions from

```
fun fold f base [] = base
  | fold f base (x::rest) = f x (fold f base rest);
fun add x y = x+y;
fun sumList L = fold add 0 L;
```

to

```
fun fold2 f base [] = SOME(base)
  | fold2 f base (x::rest) = f (SOME x) (fold2 f base rest);
fun add2 x y = SOME (x + y);
fun sumList2 L = fold2 add2 NONE L;
```

The add and fold2 functions both compile, but when I try to run variations of sumList2 I get operand don't agree errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear what the purpose of the options are; do you want to add the numbers inside *int option list*s? E.g. `[SOME 1, SOME 2, NONE, SOME 3]`. Or even *int option list list*s? E.g. `[[SOME 1, NONE], [NONE, SOME 2, SOME 3], [], [NONE, NONE, NONE]]`. Or are you trying to write fold using optional types on lists that don't contain optional values?

Your problem lies in the type of `f`'s arguments. In `fold2`, it can be inferred to have type

```
'a option -> 'b option -> 'b option
```

because the first argument is always `(SOME x)`, which has type *'a option*, the second argument is always `(fold2 f base rest)`, which has type *'b option* because of `fold2`'s base case, and returns *'b option* for the same reason. Your `add2`, however, has type

```
int -> int -> int option
```

You could do one of the following things to fix this:

- Your `add2` assumes that its operands are integers, not integer options; i.e. you're writing `SOME (x + y)`, and you can only add `x` and `y` when they're just numbers. Depending on what it is you're doing, `add2` could treat its operands as optional; e.g.

  ```
  fun add2 NONE b = b
    | add2 a NONE = a
    | add2 (SOME x) (SOME y) = SOME (x + y)
  ```

  would treat `NONE`s as `0`s. So would e.g.

  ```
  fun add2 a b = SOME (Option.getOpt (a, 0) + Option.getOpt (b, 0))
  ```

  but they would differ in the case of `add2 (NONE, NONE)` being either `NONE` or `SOME 0`.
- Your `fold2` is kind of pointless in the sense that it always wraps a `SOME` around the `x`: If that's *always* the case, then why ever do it? You can make `fold2` responsible for discarding `NONE`s, e.g.

  ```
  fun fold2 f base [] = base
    | fold2 f base (NONE::rest) = fold2 f base rest
    | fold2 f base (SOME x::rest) = f x (fold2 f base rest)
  ```

  in which case its type becomes

  ```
  ('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a option list -> 'b
  ```

  and you've created a special kind of fold that simultaneously discards `NONE`s. I'd probably prefer to have a separate function that does that and use it in combination with a regular fold:

  ```
  fun fold f base [] = base
    | fold f base (x::rest) = f x (fold f base rest)

  fun somes [] = []
    | somes (NONE::xs) = somes xs
    | somes (SOME x::xs) = x::somes xs

  fun curry f x y = f (x, y)

  fun sumListOption xs = fold (curry op+) 0 (somes xs)
  ```

Still, it depends entirely on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize that my problem lied within not handling add2 correctly. The end goal is to do addition where it could be [[SOME(1),SOME(2),SOME(3)],[SOME(4),SOME(5)]], but this was just my first step on the fold, so that I could map it to a list of lists. This is very helpful, thank you so much!